# How do I set Aptana to close all tabs on exit?

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I keep getting a cluttered mess of tabs from various projects. If I close Aptana, I don't want it to reopen all tabs on startup. How do I set this? I could not find it in the preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is an option in Aptana Studio or Eclipse to close all opened editors on exit.  To reduce the clutter, the recommend way is to use Preferences > General > Editors and check the "Close editors automatically" option.  It doesn't apply to the restart scenario, but rather it is for closing existing opened editors automatically when you open a new one during the active session if the number of opened editors has reached the upper limit you set, so you are guaranteed to not exceed the total number of opened files.

Comment: You can also ask for that feature at http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa